# Reverse proxy with content manipulation

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, varnish

Is it possible to combine two “data streams” to create a website with nginx or varnish as a reverse proxy? For example I have a “main site” the reverse proxy serves, where I somewhere have a mark, that is going to be replaced. Then I have another “site” with content. And this content has to go, where the replacement mark in the “main site” was before.

Is this possible?

Comment: With custom code? Sure, anything is possible. The question though, is why are you doing this? What problem are you trying to solve by having two sites?

Comment: @EEAA a closed source CMS, that only accepts text - even through DB everything gets filtered out. I have to add some dynamic content to it. So I'd like to use the "main site" as a template and add my content.

Answer (score 0):

For example this can do this: http://webcleaner.sourceforge.net/ or also Squid can do this, see: http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/ContentAdaptation